# JavaScript cookies and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I am working on a project using cookies on the client-side. I new to creating cookies. We want to save user inputs on any form so if the user comes to another form on another page we can automatically populate that form with their inputs from the previous form.

The site is built in PHP and AngularJS but I'm working on a JavaScript solution first because I am struggling with the AngularJS version. It works well in FF and IE but Chrome is giving me an error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u. I have read other StackOverflow articles on this same exact problem but I don't understand how they say we can fix it.

My JavaScript solution has its origin here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4Zlc6pdHgM

Page one form (I'm calling it key-value-pairs.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="form_000c_fld_0_fn" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="form_000c_fld_0_ln" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="button" value="Set Cookie" onClick="doSubmit()" />
        <a href="key-value-pairs-2.html">Let's see if this works</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSubmit(){
        var customObject = {};
        customObject.name = document.getElementById("form_000c_fld_0_fn").value;
        customObject.last = document.getElementById("form_000c_fld_0_ln").value;
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(customObject);
        document.cookie = "cookieObject=" + jsonString;
    }

    function getCookie(){
        var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("=");
        var customObject = JSON.parse(nameValueArray[1]);
        document.getElementById("first_name").value = customObject.name;
        document.getElementById("last_name").value = customObject.last;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Page 2 form (I'm calling this key-value-pairs-2.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body onLoad="getCookie()">
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="first_name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="last_name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <a href="key-value-pairs.html">Let's test another one</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSubmit(){
        var customObject = {};
        customObject.name = document.getElementById("form_000c_fld_0_fn").value;
        customObject.last = document.getElementById("form_000c_fld_0_ln").value;
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(customObject);
        document.cookie = "cookieObject=" + jsonString;
    }

    function getCookie(){
        var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("=");
        var customObject = JSON.parse(nameValueArray[1]);
        document.getElementById("first_name").value = customObject.name;
        document.getElementById("last_name").value = customObject.last;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error appears on the second page and when I debug I it's either happening here - var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("="); or here - var customObject = JSON.parse(nameValueArray[1]);

Comment: You're getting that error because you're trying to `JSON.parse(undefined)` i.e., `nameValueArray[1]` is `undefined`. Double check the value of `nameValueArray` and verify you're parsing cookies correctly.

Answer (score 0):

your code assumes that only a single cookie is present. Try these functions for setting and getting cookies..

```
function setCookie(name, value) {
    var cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + ";";
    document.cookie = cookie;
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var chunks = document.cookie.split(";");
    for(var i=chunks.length; i--;){
        if(chunks[i].trim().split("=")[0].trim() == name){
            return chunks[i].trim().split("=")[1].trim();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```